# What is the simplest way to create pagination using pure JavaScript without third party plugin?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, plugins, pagination

I wonder about any customized JavaScript Framework, which can be used multiple times in a single html page.

Answer (score 1):

There are many third party libraries of pagination that we can use, but there will be some project limitations where we **can't use any external dependencies**. Keeping this in my mind, I have created a **custom JavaScript plugin for pagination**. You will find this very easy to understand and it can be customized too. ;)

Below is some code examples of usage:

```
var array1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'];
var array2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50'];

var p1 = new Pagination(
           document.getElementById('abc'),
           array1,
           function(index, el){
              console.log(index, el);
           });
var p2 = new Pagination(document.getElementById('mno'), array2);
```

You can find a full example on this [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mbe4PXqrqql7TUpVPsnf?p=preview) link.